# How to Stop the Flood of onNewPicture()s?

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

In my tiny application, I get what I need from a web page after the first [onNewPicture()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.PictureListener.html#onNewPicture%28android.webkit.WebView,%20android.graphics.Picture%29).

But WebView's PictureListener keeps bombarding my application with `onNewPicture()` callbacks... This is despite [WebSettings.setBlockNetworkImage()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setBlockNetworkImage%28boolean%29) set to `true`.

Is there a way to tell WebView to stop listening/sending/processing `onNewPicture()`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to tell WebView to stop listening/sending/processing onNewPicture()s?

Off the cuff, I would call `setPictureListener(null)` on the `WebView`, once you no longer need to be notified.

Note that `PictureListener` is marked as deprecated, though off the top of my head I have no idea what is replacing it.

Comment: Thanks! "deprecated" means it's still available (for backward compatibility), but not recommended for use, right?

Comment: @uTubeFan: Right. However, I'd be a tad more nervous about this one, simply because it is tied into WebKit. It is conceivable that upstream changes in WebKit are driving the deprecation and that support for `PictureListener` might be totally lost in some future release. I feel more comfortable about Google maintaining backwards compatibility when they have more control over matters. I'd just keep a close eye on any new Android OS releases and confirm that `PictureListener` still works, plus see if there is a better-supported alternative going forward.

Comment: I just tested an implementation of your proposed `setPictureListener(null)` and it works! I wonder now whether `WebSettings.setBlockNetworkLoads(false)` would achieve the same effect (with the added benefit of reducing "bandwidth consumption").